# Chrome extension to force Coursera videos to be entirely cached

Tags: chrome, mooc

When I pause a Coursera video for too long it often has issue loading the rest of the video. I'm looking for a browser extension that can:

- force Coursera videos to be entirely cached when I open them
- works with Google Chrome (and Windows 7 if OS-dependent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists no such Chrome extension to force Coursera videos to be entirely cached. Instead, try to download the videos via e.g. [StreamTransport](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7186/903) or [DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/).