# Software for capturing a proprietary flash livestream

Tags: video, screen-recording

Any idea on how to capture a HD livestream which is broadcast via a proprietary Flash plugin? It is **not** FLV format.

Comment: Maybe StreamTransport? A link to an exemple would help, if that's public. FYI: [StreamTransport for Linux/Mac: detect and download videos from any website](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7186/903)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Thank you. I tried StreamTransport now, but Symatec virus scanner is warning me and blocking the site, and another software site is also giving warnings. So I don't trust it - would setup a sandbox environment first.

Comment: I saw StreamTransport's website has disappeared indeed, and been replaced by some dubious looking website. Unsure why :/